# App crashing while trying to take new photo

Tags: android, crash, camera

I am developing a customized camera app. when app starts camera opens there are three buttons at bottom.

1. Capture (To take picture).
2. Take New (return from preview to camera to take picture again.)
3. Not using for anything.

Everything works fine. pressing capture takes the picture and previews the taken picture accurately. But when I press take new button to come into camera mode from preview mode the app crashes don't have any idea what I am doing wrong. following is the code I am using.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


   protected static final String TAG = null;
   private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    static int result;
    static int degrees = 90;
    private Button captureButton, btn_new;
    public FrameLayout preview;
    private static File mediaFile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
     captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get an image from the camera
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        }
    );
    btn_new = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_new);
    btn_new.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mCamera = getCameraInstance();

            //preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            //preview.addView(mPreview);
        }
    });

}

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){

            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } 
    else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    Context context = null; 
    try{
        c = Camera.open();
        //setCameraDisplayOrientation(MainActivity, 0, c);
        c.setDisplayOrientation(degrees);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Camera is not available" ,           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return c;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Thanks in Advance.
Finally 
here is my error logcat:

---

02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.example.facebooktag.MainActivity.getCameraInstance(MainActivity.java:136)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.example.facebooktag.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:66)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Unable to see anything in logcat have any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to get LogCat working first. Where are you running this application? If it is on device with no rear-facing camera, or emulator, you will likely get null back from Camera.open(). Thus, NullPointerException.

Comment: I am running on device that have a both cameras. So, I dont think that is a problem. As I said in my question camera is taking picture and previewing it and also picture is saving successfully.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace you have there? Your problem might be this `java.lang.NullPointerException 02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at com.example.facebooktag.MainActivity.getCameraInstance(MainActivity.java:136) 02-21 18:24:01.868: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at com.example.facebooktag.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:66) 02-21 ` You are somehow accessing null object. If this is not the full stack trace post the full there you can see on what class and line the problem originates.

Comment: This was just error logcat. full logcat has more characters that are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It might because of You have taken the photo first time succesfully and acquire the camera object then again you are acquiring the camera object here.

First instance here below setcontentview.

// Create an instance of Camera

```
mCamera = getCameraInstance();
```

and trying to acquire camera instance again but its already acquired.

```
btn_new = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_new);
btn_new.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        //preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        //preview.addView(mPreview);
    }
});
```

Before acquire the camera object again you should have release the first one it.

```
if(mCamera != null)
   mCamera.release();
```

and

**Make ensure you have declare permission in manifest before application tag.**

Comment: I have also tried with releasing camera first. How would I reuse it?

Comment: If I remove it how camera will open (return to capture mode from preview) ?

Comment: @nadeem gc  check in logcat you will complete log. plz post it.

Comment: Dude my logcat isn't showing anything weird , I don't know why. Can you suggest me something on that. I am also searching to make it work.

Comment: restart the eclipse will start your log if not restart the system.

Comment: did that , also some other ways but logcat shows only this            unable to open log device '/dev/log/main' no such file or directory

Comment: when I add change my onClickListener code to this `if(releaseCamera()){
    
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    }` With this app isn't crashing but, With button Again the result is same instead of opening camera.

Comment: With button Again the result is same instead of opening camera it does nothing pictured captured remained previewed. Means it behaves as the capture button behaves

Comment: can you tell me anything ?

Comment: @nadeem gc Could you please let us know what was issue in this?

Comment: yes as I told you, On button click camera doesn't restart. first I clear the camera like `mCamera.releas();` and then I again get cameraInstance so that camera restarts again to take pic but that doesn't happen. My requirement was that first when camera opens. I take the picture and picture is previewed after that  when I click New button the camera should reopen to again take picture.

Answer (score 0):

Well the null pointer exception is coming from your exception. you have

```
Context context = null;
```

and then you are trying to use it here:

```
Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Camera is not available" ,           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

without acutally initializing it anywhere.

Also in you onPause() function you should clean up after yourself. (eg. release camera, stop surface preview, that sort of thing).