# starting the same activity with button in android

Tags: android, button, android-activity

Is it possible to start the same activity on button click. 
I have a button in my MainActivity and I want that when I click that button the current Activity (MainActivity) restarts (start again) ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: yes you can.. but why do you want this ?

Comment: Call `startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this,MyActivity.class))` then call `finish()`

Comment: That's a bad practice. The onCreate cycle of activity is very expensive. If you want to update things on the activity why not create a method that will do it? and call it when you click your button.

Comment: @hardcoded. Yes I first did this, but I couldn't get it working that's why thought it other way. Here is I have posted the question that was my actual problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008272/app-crashing-while-trying-to-take-new-photo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008272/app-crashing-while-trying-to-take-new-photo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :)

```
Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
}
 });
```

But i dont understand why you wanna do this :P

Comment: Its working , but when I press backbutton the app crashes why ?

Comment: use finish(); after startActivity(intent); so that it will close current activity and disply the new one

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to launch the Intent to that Activity again. But, I don't see why you would want to do that,  jut refresh the content of the Activity calling the same activity within that activity.. is redundant and doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah you are right its pretty awkward actually my problem was something else I posted the question yesterday [restart camera with button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008272/app-crashing-while-trying-to-take-new-photo) here that is what I wanted.

Comment: I couldn't get solved this, that's why I thought it other way.

Comment: Its always better to solve the core problem than patch a symptom.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to reload the activity, for whatever reason,  you can use `this.recreate();` where `this` is the Activity.

Comment: This is never a good practice. Instead you should `startActivity()` for the same activity and call `finish()` in the current one.

Answer (score -5):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SameActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
```