# Restart application when i click a button

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I need that my application restarts when click a button, for more info I need simulate thant I push back key and open application again.
I supose that i can close application with `finish();` but how can i do to launch `onCrete()` again? 
is there other way to do this?

thanks

Comment: startActivity()  with do your job..

Answer (score 2):

Call your Activity using an Intent. It will launch the activity again.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //this will always start your activity as a new task
startActivity(intent);
```

You can also add, `android:launchMode="singleTask"` inside your Manifest so that only one instance of your activity will be maintained at any time.

Same thing [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025412/starting-the-same-activity-with-button-in-android) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
             .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

To restart your application you can use alarm manager to make your activity open after you exit the app.

```
AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0));
android.os.Process.sendSignal(android.os.Process.myPid(), android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
```